# How can I get SASS working in Netbeans for mac

Tags: ruby, netbeans, sass

Does anyone one know what to add in the Sass path in a mac? All the tutorials I have found are for Windows: https://medium.com/@raaechelb/sass-installing-on-netbeans-and-getting-started-2b5ce99d985c

I have installed Ruby and Sass. I can get SCSS to compile if I use --watch in the command line, but I can't seem to get Netbeans to see SASS within the IDE. I have also tried the file path /usr/bin/sass suggested on the Netbeans website:https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-editing-css.html

I keep getting 'SASS executable must be a valid file' - Any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2MD7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your terminal and type `which sass`. It should give you the path that you can copy and paste in NetBeans.